# ActionBar реализовать снизу или альтернатива ему

Tags: java, android, android-layout, actionbar, android-toolbar

Как сделать эти вкладки снизу? Смотрел в сторону PagerTabStrip (на нем можно реализовать такой же вид, как от этих вкладок?)

Пример с ActionBar

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    //mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    MyPagerAdapter mAdapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),  this);


    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapterViewPager);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };

    /** Creating Android Tab */
    ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Android")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.android)
            .setTabListener(tabListener);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    /** Creating Apple Tab */
    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Apple")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.apple)
            .setTabListener(tabListener);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);


}
```

}

Вот есть пример с ToolBar

```
 public class IconTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_icon_tabs);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
    };

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        // return null to display only the icon
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Для ToolBar xml файл

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто поместите табы вниз экрана...

Comment: выложил xml файл. TabLayout ставил позицию снизу, ну не сработало

Comment: Нет, вы не поставили его вниз. Вы прописали табам `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` - а оно работает только если табы в RelativeLayout находятся. А у вас табы в AppBarLayout. Перенесите табы в координатор и задайте им `layout_gravity="bottom"`

Comment: спасибо, это работает))

Comment: Написал в ответ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть вопроса сводится к позиционированию элементов разметки на экране.

В данном случае нужно просто перенести `TabLayout` из `AppBarLayout` в `CoordinatorLayout` и задать для табов положение внизу через

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: А разве не `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`?

Comment: @Flippy, нет, т.к. координатор наследует `FrameLayout`, не `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял